# Möbius tranformation taking reals to reals can be written with real coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on this one (from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis):

*A Fractional Linear Transformation of form $\displaystyle T(z) = \frac{a z + b}{c z + d}$ which takes the real numbers into the real numbers can be written in a way where all the coefficients are real.*

I'm pretty sure I know a way to get the answer.

First, the thing is a constant exactly when $ad - bc = 0$. Then you're done. If not, some coefficient is not zero. in that case, you can change variables and stuff around in a way so that you can assume WLOG $a \ne 0$.

Then, you pick three different real-valued inputs and show that all the three remaining coefficients $b, c, d$ are real-valued.

My question is:

**Is there an easier way to do this, without using more advanced complex analysis (which I don't know yet)**

Comment: Um...What do you mean by "More Advanced Complex Analysis"?

Comment: We've been introduced to the idea of an analytic function, talked a little about complex differentiability being the same as $\mathbb{R}^2$ differentiability plus Cauchy-Riemann stuff.

Comment: No integration theory, and no "power series uniqueness" stuff.

Comment: Hmm...With no other tools than arithmetic and differentiability, I'd say just beat the crap out of it like you said you can do. Do case-by-case and force it out. But, I'm an amateur, and you should still look for a better way. Maybe some of the real mathematicians here have better ideas.

Comment: Dude - You put some thought into your question, provided a possible solution (which isn't rock-hard, but whatever), and so your post is legit (IMHO). I don't know about people respond to the "homework" label.

Comment: It turns out this question is essentially answered under https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105859/139123, although the form of the question there was somewhat different.

Answer (score -1):

**It turns out that this is not an answer to the OP's question. I will leave this answer nevertheless, perhaps someone might find it useful for something. This was my fault for not reading the question more carefully**

I will start the answer with an exercise. We will assume throughout that $a\neq 0$, and $ad-bc\neq 0$. Throughout, $L$ will denote a linear fractional transformation that sends extended reals to the extended reals, that satisfies the conditions above.

**Exercise**: Let $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, and $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ be two triples of extended complex numbers (the complex numbers with the point at infinity include). Then their is a unique linear fractional transformation, $L$ such that $L(z_i)=w_i,i=1,2,3.$

Now to take on the literal statement of the question, if a linear fractional transformation takes the reals to the reals, then it is a linear function (and takes infinity to infinity), but this is not so interesting. More interesting (the one I assume that you want to prove) is that a LFT that takes the *extended reals* to the *extended reals* (the reals with infinity included) mat be written to have all real coefficients. Since by your remark, that we may assume $a\neq 0$, multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{a}$, so now without loss of generality, we may assume that $a=1$.

We will now invoke our exercise. If we say where we send $\{0,1,\infty\}$, we completely determine the LFT. Again, if we send infinity to infinity, we have a linear function. Let us assume that we send infinity to some real number. If $L(z)=\frac{z+b}{cz+d}$, then $L(\infty)=\frac{1}{c}$. If we assume that $L$ sends extended reals to extended reals, the, $\frac{1}{c}$ is real and therefore ,so is $c$. Likewise $L(0)=\frac{b}{d}$, which is also real if $d\neq 0$(we will also need to deal with the case when $d=0$. 
Since our linear fractional transformation does not send infinity to infinity, the number, $-\frac{d}{c}$ is real, since $L(-\frac{d}{c})=\infty$. Since $c$ is real, so is $d$. Since $\frac{b}{d}$ is real, so is $b$, since $d$ is real. Now suppose that $d=0$. Then the LFT is of the form, $\frac{z+b}{cz}=\frac{1}{c}+\frac{b}{cz}$. We still know that $c$ is real, the previous argument for this did not require $d\neq 0$. Now pick $z=1$ and plug it into $\frac{1}{c}+\frac{b}{cz}$, which concludes this argument.

Comment: Let $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, and $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ be two **triples**?

Comment: You wrote "Then their is a unique linear fractional transformation, $L$ such that $L(z_i)=w_i,i=1,2,3.$ ". Sure, of course there is: But I explicitly said that I can't assume that. If I could have, I wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: Anyway, I had already solved it in a way similar to the way you did above. That's why the question was **Is there an easier way to do this**.

Comment: @ Mulling Right I want $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, and $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ to be  triples of extended complex numbers such that the three were distinct. As to you not wanting to assume that I do remember reading that and it somehow got mentally replaced with one of the comments that said that you wanted a proof not involving power series or power series.

Comment: To your original question I cannot see a way of proving this without using the exercise, that is on the surface (more elaborate techniques might give something however).